# How to show image for 3 seconds on every button click?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an HTML/js code where on button click I have it show a picture. I have the following written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source here"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let pictures = [array of pics here];
        function show() {
            let index = randInt(0, words.length - 1);
            document.getElementById("picture").src = "images/" + pictures[index] + ".jpg";

        }
        function hide() {
            window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('picture').style.display='none';", 3000);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

This will make the image disappear, but when I click the button again, an image doesn't show. Is the function permanently hiding the image? How can I make it so for every button press an image shows up for 3 seconds and then disappears? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This code hides an element with an ID of `picture` after 3 seconds. Did you mean it to do something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Firstly, you've provided incomplete code and I imagine you're corresponding `show` function isn't set up to correctly remove the display=none styling. Secondly, `setTimeout` accepts a function, not a string.

Comment: @junvar It also accepts a string, it will execute it with `eval()`.

Comment: Learned something new, thank you.

Comment: @junvar Thanks is there a way to remove the display styling on button click?

Comment: @Clome `document.getElementById('picture').style.display = 'block'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want it so that on button click an image will show and automatically disappear after a few seconds. I need this to happen for every button click, not just the first

Comment: Ah, then don't select the image by ID. That can only ever reference _one_ image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function show() {
        let index = randInt(0, pictures.length - 1);
        let pic = document.getElementById("picture");
        pic.src = "images/" + pictures[index] + ".jpg";
        pic.style.display = 'block';
        window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('picture').style.display='none';", 3000);
    }
    // delete your hide() function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please explain what your last line does in relation to everything else?

Comment: Also more specifically how is it that my timeout function is nullified on button click?

Comment: The last line `pic.style.display = 'block';` unhides the picture that was hidden by `display='none'`

Comment: Upon further thought, you need to roll the hide() function into the end of the show() function. So, show the image, then set a timer to hide it. I edit my code above.